# Find keyword and iterate through file to find the next keyword

Tags: python-3.x, loops, iteration

I am searching a file for a specific keyword. From there I want to search the previous lines for an additional keyword.
Ex: Search text for "source". Then search the previous 15 lines of text for the keyword "destination".
The problem is, the second keyword appears within about a 15-20 line range from the first keyword, so I can't just put lines[i-15] because it won't return the same result for each instance of finding the keyword "source".

I've tried setting a variable that will increment if the second keyword is not found in the line above so that it will keep iterating and searching but it through an error.

First attempt...

````
   keyword_2 ="destination
   j = 
   if re.match(keyword_1, line):
                lineafter = lines[i + j]
                lineafter_split= lineafter.split(' ')

            if value2 and cell_value in line:
                if 'access-list' not in line:
                    if 'nat' not in line:
                        lineafter_2 = lines[i + 1]
                        if 'description' not in lineafter_2:
                            print(lineafter_2)




Second attempt ...
```keyword_1 ="source"
   keyword_2 ="destination
   j=1
   for i, line in enumerate(lines):
       if keyword_1 in line:
          prev_line=lines[i - j]
           for i in range(1,15):
               if w in prev_line:
                   print(prev_line)
               else:j= j+1
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay , so what I understood is that you want to iterate through the text , and then look for the second Keyword prior to that.

However as I am unclear if you want to  prevent the search from going too far , or if you want to look for the second keyword until there are no previous lines, I will give you a function that does both.

```
def looking_for_keywords(lines, keyword_1, keyword_2, range = None):
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if keyword_1 in line:
            j=0
            max = range if range else i
            not_found = True
            while j<max and not_found:
                j+=1 
                not_found = not(keyword_2 in lines[i-j])
            if not_found:
                print('Not Found')
            else:
                print(f'Found first at {i} and second at {i-j}')
```

Note that your answer does not give the same result ,and will behave weirdly if `i <3`

Comment: Thanks. Yeah the idea was to have the script just find keyword_2 and stopping. However, with my file, keyword_2  appears every 15-20 lines from keyword_1, so the range has been working great so far. 
It would be better practice to have it stop after seeing keyword_2 in case the file changes. I'll test yours out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer in case anyone else is having the same issue.

```
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if keyword_1 in line:
            prev_line=lines[i - 1]
            for k in range(1,3):
                j=k
                prev_line=lines[i - j]
                print(prev_line)
 #Then search for keyword_2
```

Comment: It allows me to iterate through the previous lines and then search for the keyword.
The range function allows me to specify how far back I would like to go, I add that to the prev_lines variable and then search for the second term. It'll iterate back and then find the second keyword.

Comment: If ``ì<3`` that means you will be printing the last lines.